# How to recall a method n amount of times?

Tags: java, methods

trying to recall a method here (so that it generates different results 100 times using a for loop)

Here is what I have in the main method:

```
for (int i = 0; i<99; i++) { 
            double scaleFitness = ScalesSolution.ScalesFitness(randomNumberFile);
            System.out.print(scaleFitness + ", ");
        }
```

and this is the method I'm trying to call 100 times (in the ScalesSolution class):

```
public static double ScalesFitness(ArrayList<Double> weights)
    {
        int n = scasol.length();
        double lhs = 0.0, rhs = 0.0;
        if (n > weights.size()) return(-1);

        for(int i = 0; i < n; i++){
            if(scasol.charAt(i) == '0'){
                lhs += weights.get(i);
            }
            else if (scasol.charAt(i) == '1') {
                rhs += weights.get(i);
            }
        }
        return(Math.abs(lhs-rhs));  
    }
```

This however prints the same value 100 time over.

Comment: But aren't you passing the same value in every time?  You should get the same response every time.

Comment: It sure looks like `ScalesFitness` _ought_ to return the same value when passed the same input.

Comment: BTW, for 100 print you need `i < 100` instead of `i < 99`.

Comment: If I rerun the program, different results are generated. (but obviously the same result is printed 100 times over)

Comment: Java convention is to start method names with lowercase letters.  Also, what exactly do you want to randomize?

Comment: A fitness solution to a set of weights that are in a text file. The ScalesFitness generates different fitness results when rerun every time.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your method "ScaleFitness" and the output of this method is dependent on two variables:

1. weights
2. scasol

It seems these variables stay the same for the whole run of the program. So it is not surprising that your output is the same.

If you want a different output for each run of your loop. You need to reset at least one of these variables to a new value.

Btw. methods in Java always start with a lowercase. Classes start with an uppercase.

Comment: I understand what you're saying, but if I rerun the whole program, the  ScalesFitness method generates a different result to the previous one.

Comment: Of course.Because these values are set with new values, and I would guess that they are set in a randomized way.
If you could post the code, where these values are set, we can verify that assumption.

Answer (score 0):

```
public static double scalesFitness(ArrayList<Double> weights)
{
    double randomElement = weights[((int) (Math.random() * weights.size()))];
```

This will enable you to retrieve a random element in the array, for manipulation later.